# continue to create tables in for loop after exception is raised

Tags: python, sql, list, python-2.7, try-except

I have a list of employees and I want to create tables for them. I want to continue creating tables even if one of the table creations fail. I am using try/except block but when a table creation fails, it fails totally. I am trying below code. Appreciate your help!

```
employees=[1,2,3,4]
for p in employees:
    create_table = f"""create table dim_{p}"""
    try:
        conn.execute(create_table)
        print(f"success for {p}")
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to create table for {p} with error : {{e}}")
```

Comment: If you want to continue, don't raise another exception in your `except:` code. Just print the error message and the code will keep running.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can save the exception object for later without raising it.

```
employees=[1,2,3,4]
exceptions = []
for p in employees:
    create_table = f"""create table dim_{p}"""
    try:
        conn.execute(create_table)
        print(f"success for {p}")
    except Exception as e:
        exceptions.append((p, e))  # save info as a tuple
if exceptions:  # after your loop over employees is complete
    # handle your errors how you like
    fail_msg = '\n'.join([f"{exception[0]} ; {exception[1]}" for exception in exceptions])
    raise Exception(f"Failed to create table for the following employees:\n{fail_msg}")
```

When I run this (since conn is not defined via any imports) I get:

```
Exception: Failed to create table for the following employees:
1 ; name 'conn' is not defined
2 ; name 'conn' is not defined
3 ; name 'conn' is not defined
4 ; name 'conn' is not defined
```

Comment: Appreciate it so much! can you please elaborate how to get the `fail_msg` here. I am not quite clear on that. @LastTigerEyes

Comment: It's just putting the list of tuples (employee, exception object) saved into more nicely formatted string so when you print it it's not all on one line.

Also looks like I made a typo, so will fix that now.

Comment: To answer your question about fail_msg more specifically, I am leveraging str.join() ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join ) built-in function, and a list comprehension ( https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension ).

Answer (score 0):

> I am using try/except block but when a table creation fails, it fails totally.

this is because you have used `raise Exception(f"Failed to create table for {p} with error : {{e}}")`

raising an exception, leading to the program interrupting. To avoid that, simply don't use `raise`.

For better understanding, look at the example below:

```py
employees=["1","2",[1,2],"4"]

for i in employees :
    try :
        print(int(i))
    except :
        print("error on" , i)
```

This will output :

```
1
2
error on [1, 2]
4
```